# Bare workflow Android app with product variations with different app id/package names fails to initialize simulator ANDROID

Tags: react-native, expo

I have an application that was on SDK-44, I am upgrading to SDK-50(50.0.11), and I used Install app variants on the same device, I followed the documentation correctly but when trying to run the command to execute in the simulator using a variant in the development case, I receive the error below, it is an error that I do not receive running on the old version.

**Command run - expo run:android --variant=developmentDebug**

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 20s

586 actionable tasks: 26 executed, 560 up-to-date › Opening br.com.integralservices.development.mob/.MainActivity on Pixel_4_API_34

CommandError: Couldn't open Android app with activity "br.com.integralservices.development.mob/.MainActivity" on device "Pixel_4_API_34".

The app might not be installed, try installing it with: npx expo run:android -d Pixel_4_API_34

Activity class {br.com.integralservices.development.mob/br.com.integralservices.development.mob.MainActivity} does not exist.
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tp7nO.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUuuu.png)

```
I believe it is caused by the "namespace" parameter in build.gradle, I can only run it in the simulator if I keep the applicationId the same, as in the example below:

namespace "com.integralservices"
defaultConfig {
   applicationId "com.integralservices"
   minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
   targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
   versionCode 1
   versionName "1.0"
   buildConfigField("boolean", "REACT_NATIVE_UNSTABLE_USE_RUNTIME_SCHEDULER_ALWAYS",    (findProperty("reactNative.unstable_useRuntimeSchedulerAlways") ?: true).toString())
}
flavorDimensions "env"
productFlavors {
   production {
      dimension "env"
      applicationId 'br.com.integralservices.production.mob'
   }
   development {
      dimension "env"
      applicationId 'com.integralservices'
   }
   staging {
      dimension "env"
      applicationId 'br.com.integralservices.staging.mob'
   }
}

In the project in the SDK 44 version, it is like this below and works correctly, however in  this version of react-native it still did not have this "namespace" parameter:

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "br.com.integralservices.development.mob"
    minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}

flavorDimensions "env"
productFlavors {
    production {
       dimension "env"
       applicationId 'br.com.integralservices.production.mob'
    }
    development {
       dimension "env"
       applicationId 'br.com.integralservices.development.mob'
    }
    staging {
       dimension "env"
       applicationId 'br.com.integralservices.staging.mob'
    }
 }
```

can anybody help me?

What platform(s) does this occur on?
Android

SDK Version
50

Environment
expo-env-info 1.2.0 environment info:

```
 System:

 OS: macOS 14.4

 Shell: 5.9 - /bin/zsh

 Binaries:

 Node: 18.19.1 - /usr/local/bin/node

 Yarn: 1.22.21 - /opt/homebrew/bin/yarn

 npm: 10.2.4 - /usr/local/bin/npm

 Managers:

 CocoaPods: 1.15.2 - /opt/homebrew/bin/pod

 SDKs:

 iOS SDK:

 Platforms: DriverKit 23.4, iOS 17.4, macOS 14.4, tvOS 17.4, visionOS 1.1, watchOS 10.4

 Android SDK:

 Android NDK: 25.1.8937393

 IDEs:

 Android Studio: 2021.2 AI-212.5712.43.2112.8609683

 Xcode: 15.3/15E204a - /usr/bin/xcodebuild

 npmPackages:

 expo: ~50.0.13 => 50.0.13

 react: 18.2.0 => 18.2.0

 react-native: 0.73.5 => 0.73.5

 Expo Workflow: bare
```

**Minimal reproducible example Run**

```
yarn dev-android
```

https://github.com/geydson/expo-bare-instal-variants

Did anyone have the same problem?

Run the variants in the simulator